# Why is "while read -r a" command unable to read string that is not newline terminated?

Tags: shell, while-loop

Here is my shell script.

```
printf "foo" | (read -r a; echo $a)
printf "bar" | while read -r a
do
    echo $a
done
```

Here is the output.

```
$ sh foo.sh 
foo
```

My question is: Why is `foo` printed but `bar` not printed? When `read -r a` is able to read a string that is not newline-terminated why is it unable to do so when it used as a condition of a `while loop`?

Comment: Try `printf "bar" | { while read -r a; do echo $a; done; echo a=$a; }`

Comment: Read returns non-zero when it detects the end of file, so it makes the assignment to the variable, but the while loop is not entered.